# Accessing HTML table values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5 with phonegap. I have a table defined as follows.

```
<table id = "myTable">
   <tr><td>Name</td><td class="center">:</td><td><div id="name"></div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td>Age</td><td class="center">:</td><td><div id="age"></div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td>Country</td><td class="center">:</td><td><div id="country"></div> </td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to set values to "name", "age", and "country" from javascript. I tried it as follows.

```
document.getElementById('name') = 'John'
```

But this doesn't give me the required output. How can that be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'John';`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/6eyLL/)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML= 'John'
```

Comment: a div does not have value attribute

Comment: @Dr. Dan: You've edited your answer and replaced `value` with `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('name').innerText = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set innerHTML to set html inside an element.

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML= 'John'
```